# React + Laravel 7 API - CORS issue

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, api

I'm trying to do a simple Sign Up form (just studying) and i'm having a problem with CORS. I've tried everything that I have found but none worked. From what I learned, Laravel 7 already works to prevent CORS issues but mine does not. Here are my codes:

**api.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'auth',
], function () {
    Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
    Route::post('signup', 'AuthController@signup');
    Route::group([
        'middleware' => 'auth:api'
    ], function () {
        Route::get('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
        Route::get('user',  'AuthController@user');
    });
});


Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

**cors.php**

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure your settings for cross-origin resource sharing
    | or "CORS". This determines what cross-origin operations may execute
    | in web browsers. You are free to adjust these settings as needed.
    |
    | To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
    |
    */

    'paths' => ['api/*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => false,

];
```

**Kernel.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel {

    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    ];
}
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: "",
      email: "",
      password: "",
      password_confimation: ""
    };
  }

  /**
   * Generic handleChange
   * @param {The element changing} e 
   */
  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name] : e.target.value
    });
  }

  handleSubmit = () => {
    
    const user = {
      name: this.state.name,
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password,
      password_confimation: this.state.password_confimation
    };

    axios.post("localhost:8000/api/auth/signup", user)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        console.log(response.data);
      });

  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <label>Name:
          <input type="text" name="name" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
        </label>
        <br />
        <label>E-mail:
          <input type="text" name="email" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
        </label>
        <br />
        <label>Password:
          <input type="password" name="password" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
        </label>
        <br />
        <label>Password Confirmation:
          <input type="password" name="password_confimation" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
        </label>
        <br />
        <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Sign Up</button>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default App;
```

Using Postman the Laravel works, it only occurs if I use React. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How did you solde it? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: On my case, I only putted "http://" in my axios request. It was that simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by putting "http://" in my axios request.